# How can I delete the "Recents" pictures when selecting a profile photo?

Tags: itunes, mac

How can I delete the photos within the recent section?
I tried pressing the delete button, but it didn't delete the image from the list.

[image: Screenshot of issue.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is a bit complicated.

To delete the Photos in recent, you need to first navigate over to:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent Pictures
```

(**Finder** > **Go** > **Go to Folder**)

There you will find all your recent pictures. However, you can't just delete those pictures. You have to also delete it from the plist file available at:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent Pictures/Recents.plist
```

Just open it in Xcode or any text editor, and delete the dictionaries under the array.

A picture in the plist will look something like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>cropInfo</key>
    <dict>
        <key>cropViewInfo</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PRS</key>
            <dict>
                <key>px</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
                <key>py</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
                <key>r</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
                <key>sh</key>
                <real>0.390625</real>
                <key>sw</key>
                <real>0.390625</real>
            </dict>
            <key>cropViewSize.height</key>
            <real>200</real>
            <key>cropViewSize.width</key>
            <real>200</real>
            <key>zoomValue</key>
            <real>0.0</real>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>cropSize</key>
    <string>{200, 200}</string>
    <key>original</key>
    <string>68937D05-204D-4AD8-A98F-2DB8E9EF945F.png</string>
</dict>
```

You can delete each dictionary/picture manually by looking at the string parameter.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)